# How to create a simple Mysql search engine

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I've written this simple code to retrieve a value of a table which starts with a variable coming from a POST method: i know that in my table there is only that value, so i want to retrieve the unique value in a string variable:

```
... 
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE contenuto LIKE :contenuto%"; 
$query_params = array(
      ':contenuto' => $_POST['contenuto']
);
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}catch (PDOException $ex){
}
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$this = $row['contenuto'];
echo $this;
...
```

But this code doesn't work because nothing in showed by echo.. any help?

Comment: Why aren't you printing out the PDFException object? You should also not be using `$this` as a regular variable.

Comment: [`$this` throws an error.](http://codepad.org/NpVg6LCM)

Comment: can you explein me what i have to do? thanks

Comment: `var_dump($ex);` to see the PDOException, if there is one. Also see above about using `$this` as you are.

Comment: var_dump($ex); -> i insert this but nothing is stamped on the screen

Comment: how i have to use $this, so?

Comment: You *don't use `$this`*. It's a special variable with special meaning within an object and reserved, so you can't use it.

Comment: ok i've changed its name, but nothing is still showed

Comment: Echo some string at the end, like `echo 'test';`. If you don't see `test` on the page when you reload, there's a parse error somewhere else. Turn error reporting on (the PHP manual will help you with this).

Comment: nothing! test is not showed, where is the problem?

Comment: eliminating try and catch method the string test is now showed..

Comment: ok solved! i missed a reference, stupid error thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` wildcard should be in the bound variable and not the prepared statement

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE contenuto LIKE :contenuto"; 
$query_params = array(
      ':contenuto' => $_POST['contenuto'] . '%'
);
```

Comment: @Peppegiuseppe try `'%'.$_POST['contenuto'].'%'` are you sure the value you're searching for is in the db?

Comment: yes i'm sure! i'm searching 'wei', and in my column there is 'weihowareyou'

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing bind parameters with literals. Try this on for size:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE contenuto LIKE CONCAT(:contenuto, '%')";
```

Comment: @Peppegiuseppe - See my comment under your question.